# Insert to table from set returning function with parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, composite-types

This is probably something simple but couldn't figure it out.

I've table Summary and function `GetSummary` that returns row as set of Summary.  I can query it like this

```
SELECT GetSummary(arg1, arg2)
GetSummary
-----------
(val1, val2, val3)
```

And like this that returns the actual columns:

```
SELECT * FROM GetSummary(arg1, arg2)
col1  |   col2   | col3
------------------------
val1  |   val2   | val3
```

Insertion to Summary works fine:

```
INSERT INTO Summary (SELECT * FROM GetSummary(arg1, arg2));
INSERT 0 1
```

But I can't figure out how to insert several rows at once based on columns in other table. I would like to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Summary (SELECT FROM GetSummary(OtherTable.x, OtherTable.y)
FROM OtherTable WHERE <some query>);
```

That fails because `SELECT FROM GetSummary ..` doesn't return Summary table rows. The query `SELECT * FROM GetSummary ..` would do that but then I don't know how to write the query.

**Edit**

Happened to stumble to solution few minutes after posting. The right syntax is

```
INSERT INTO Summary (SELECT (GetSummary(OtherTable.x, OtherTable.y)).*
FROM OtherTable WHERE <some query>);
```

The (X).* notation expands the select to columns.

Comment: Other columns from other table ? you mean you want only selected rows from your function table ? If so you need to inner join your table returned by function and other columns table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution appended to the question still has syntax errors. It should be:

```
INSERT INTO Summary
SELECT (GetSummary(o.x, o.y)).*
FROM   OtherTable o
WHERE  <some condition>;
```

Must:
- Only one `FROM`.

Optional:
- No parenthesis around the `SELECT` needed.
- Table alias to simplify syntax.

The manual on [**Accessing Composite Types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html#AEN7249).

---

Also, it seems that your function is supposed to return *one* (or no) row. *If* that is the case, you should drop the **`SETOF`** in the `RETURNS` clause. Make that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getsummary( ... )
   RETURNS summary AS ...
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning this up. The function indeed returns a single row.